# Constructing confidence interval for estimator with unknown standard deviation and sample size

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, estimation, inference

> Suppose you want to estimate $\pi$ using the estimator $\hat{\pi}_n = 4\times \frac{N_{circle}}{n}$, where $N_{circle}$ is the number of points that lie within the unit circle embedded in the square generated by random points that are uniformly distributed over $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$, and $n$ is the total number of points generated.  You know that $\pi$ definitely lies in $[3,4]$. Using this information, choose a number of replicates $n$ that you need to generate in order to obtain an estimate of $\pi$ that is accurate to two decimal places with 95% confidence? You can use $z_{0.95}=2$, and must explain how to use the bounds for $\pi$ given above to determine the number of replications.

> *Note: Two digits of precision is equivalent to desiring a half-width of $0.005$.*

Since we know that $\pi \in [3,4]$, we set up our confidence interval as:
$3 \leq \hat{\pi}_n - 2\times\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\leq \hat{\pi}_n +2\times\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\leq 4 $
However, I am not sure how to solve for $n$ since $S_n$ is also dependent on $n$. Does the half width note imply that $S_n=0.005$ or that the number I am subtracting from $\hat{\pi}_n$ is suppose to be $0.005$? I.e. $2\times\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} = 0.005$

If my logic is incorrect, what avenues should I explore to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you explain what "$S_n$" is intended to refer to?  It looks like some kind of standard deviation.  In this setting you know the standard deviation of the observations: it does not depend on the sample size $n.$

Comment: $S_n$ is suppose to be the standard deviation of the estimator I believe. I need to construct a confidence interval for it so that is what I assume it is.

Comment: This is a Binomial sampling problem: apply the standard formulas.

Comment: Does that not still require me to know $n$? I have no experience with sampling, just plugging and chugging formulas, so this is not so straightforward for me.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+confidence+interval+score%3A5+is%3Aanswer.

Comment: So its just $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ where $p = \tfrac \pi4$?

Comment: That's the idea -- but since you are estimating $\pi,$ you can't use $p=\pi/4.$ Instead, you have to consider arbitrary $p$ in the interval from $3/4$ to $4/4.$ In order not to under-calculate $n,$ use the value $\tilde p$ in this interval that *maximizes* the standard deviation $\tilde p(1-\tilde p).$

Comment: Using $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ does not seem correct as the $\sqrt{n}$ cancels out in the bounds when attempting to solve $2\times \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} = 0.005$. It is also maximized at $p = \tfrac 34$, however, you cannot get $0.005$ from this value it seems. What am I missing here? Can you explain why $S_n = \tilde{p}(1-\tilde{p})$ and not what I listed above? I used your standard deviation and it worked beautifully! I just don't know how you got it.

Comment: The true variance of a *single* observation is $\pi/4(1-\pi/4).$  The range of possible variances, given that you don't know $\pi,$ is the range of the function $p\to p(1-p)$ on the interval $[3,4].$  Proceed from there.